# Swift 4 - XCTAssertThrowsError failed: did not throw an error

Tags: swift, unit-testing, error-handling, xctest, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm testing the error handling for `SFSpeechRecognizer`. I'm not able to get the function to throw an error using `XCTAssertThrowsError()`.

Creating `SFSpeechRecognizer` will return an object or `nil` if there is no locale.

```
public convenience init?() // Returns speech recognizer with user's current locale, or nil if is not supported

public init?(locale: Locale) // returns nil if the locale is not supported

func createSpeechRecognization(locale : Locale) throws -> SFSpeechRecognizer {
    guard let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale) else {
        throw SpeechToTextError.speechRecognizerIsNil
    }
    return speechRecognizer
}
```

Here is the unit test function where I attempt to throw:

```
func testCreateSpeechToTextAudioSessionNotNotAvailable() {
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try sut.createSpeechRecognization(locale: Locale.current)) {error in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? SpeechToTextError, SpeechToTextError.speechRecognizerIsNil)
    }
}
```

The unit test failed due to the error:

> XCTAssertThrowsError failed: did not throw an error.

I'm not sure why it is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: Test failed because `createSpeechRecognization` was supposed to throw, but it didn't. `SFSpeechRecognizer(locale:)` is a failable initializer, but for the parameter `Locale.current` it returned a valid instance, thus `createSpeechRecognization` didn't throw. Everything works as expected.

Comment: does XCTAssertThrowsError makes createSpeechRecognization throw the exception? I want to get it to be nil so I can test the error handling.

Comment: No, it asserts whether it throws - and for `Locale.current` it didn't.

Comment: ah, thanks for clarification

Comment: Use a function `SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales()` and then try to initialize `SFSpeechRecognizer` with a locale it doesn't support

Comment: If there are SFSpeechRecognizer.unsupportedLocales(), then I'll gladly try it. I'll see if I can set the Locale with some string to get SFSpeechRecognizer  to be nil.

Answer (score 0):

`XCTAssertThrowsError` doesn't make the function throw the exception, it just asserts, thanks to @mag_zbc.

I modified the unit test to:

```
func testCreateSpeechToTextAudioSessionNotNotAvailable() {
    var locale : Locale = Locale(identifier: "pwned")

    XCTAssertThrowsError(try sut.createSpeechRecognization(locale: locale)) {error in
        XCTAssertEqual(error as? SpeechToTextError, SpeechToTextError.speechRecognizerIsNil)
    }
}
```

And it passed the test.